# Should a congregational rabbi resign based on "common public" accusations?

Tags: rabbis, employment, derech-eretz-manners

Last night, I found numerous articles published in many newspapers over the course of about the past decade regarding several students accusing a former Yeshiva principal who sexually abused them. The incident occurred many years ago, but recently, a class action lawsuit has been filed against him.

In the interim, the former principal became a congregational rabbi. Shortly after the slew of publicity occurred, the rabbi voluntarily resigned because he didn't want the shul to be embarrassed by the publicity. However, the rabbi denies the incidents.

**My question:**

Is there any halachic ruling or suggestion that states or suggests that a prominent rabbi, Talmid Chacham, or other prominent public leader should or must resign his position based on what is widely publicized news but hasn't been officially confirmed by anyone to actually be true?

In other words, should people follow this rabbi's example and spare the workplace / institution embarrassment because of what may be false publicity (aka "fake news") or should he remain in his position if he is doing a good useful job in his position. Assume that his employer has not taken any stand on his issue in either way, and has not pressured him to resign.

**Note:** I personally know this rabbi. (I am not involved in the suit, at least not yet.) Some of you may figure out who he is by my narrative. Regardless, please do not mention his name in any comments or answers.

Comment: וישא חן ושכל טוב בעיני אלקים ואדם

Comment: I'd say "והייתם נקיים מה' ומישראל" see https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%95%D7%94%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D

Comment: https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/headlines/disgraced-rabbi-part-1/ - See section on "Unsubstantiated Rumors"

Comment: @IsraelReader Great find. I read part of it. A bit much to read now, but very interesting article. I think the section you referred to my suffice for you to compose an answer.